# What is the antecedent in this passage?

Tags: meaning, antecedents, dummy-it

sample taken from a Toefl exam

> Just as painted designs on Greek pots may seem today to be purely decorative, whereas in fact they were carefully and precisely worked out so that at the time, [sic] their meaning **was** clear, so **it** is with Chinese pots.
>
> ([langlib.com](http://www.langlib.com/Mokao/TOEFL/Analysis/MTAtUjEx))

Hi everybody, my question is about the antecedent of "it", and what is the reference of "was"?

Comment: This passage seems to cause a number of difficulties ["so that at the time"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/298097/what-is-the-subject-of-the-first-sentencewhat-does-so-that-means-what-is-the) and [on the Internet](https://www.google.com/search?ei=jHY1XaCAA8GRkwXOrID4AQ&q=%22Just+as+painted+designs+on+Greek+pots+may+seem+today%22&oq=%22Just+as+painted+designs+on+Greek+pots+may+seem+today%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...9108.12410..13203...0.0..0.490.571.1j4-1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.ARGTVhCkNKU&ved=0ahUKEwig9onBkMjjAhXByKQKHU4WAB8Q4dUDCAo&uact=5)

Comment: You could say that the antecedent is the entire preceding passage (an adjunct).

Comment: @BillJ on all the sites where this passage is cited, see link above, there is the same comma.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Do you mind. It's an error and should be deleted. Or it could be parenthesised.

Comment: @BillJ That may be so or it may be a question of opinion,  but it is the original text. I have checked several sites to be absolutely sure. I believe that you are  an academic, and as such, you should know better than to alter the original text, however trivial that correction might be.

Comment: The sites are wrong in my opinion. A single comma is confusing, though parenthesising "at the time" would be better but certainly not essential. The comments below also mention the confusion caused by a single comma. I like the idea of inserting [sic].

Comment: If the preposing were reversed to give _so that their meaning was clear at the time_, I don't think anyone would be tempted to insert a comma after "clear", so why insert one in the preposed  construction?

Comment: 'so it is with' in situations like this means 'a similar situation is found with' (surrounding grammar will probably need adjusting). You could say that 'the {appropriate deducible} situation' is the retrievable **referent** for 'it', though one can over-analyse.

Comment: @BillJ "`I don't think anyone would be tempted to insert a comma after "clear", so why insert one in the preposed construction?`" nobody inserted a comma, it's in the *original* text. Just like deadrat mentioned in the other question, which I posted a link to, users can point out that the extra comma is either ungrammatical or superfluous.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A The problem here is that the actual question may be masked by a deficient example. While 'correcting' an original quote is not on, supplying a better example is. There's a difficulty here. If OP hadn't provided a link, I'd say a correction would be justified. And TOEFL status obviously doesn't inspire great confidence.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth if you disagree with my judgement, you can rollback the edit to before the source and link were added. To David, the source is from an old TOEFL paper, the OP did not write anything. I am done here.

Comment: Your use of “whereas” is wrong following “just as”. I’d recommend you sort this out first (although others would regard such practical advice as unfriendly). It’s your choice.

Comment: @David It’s not wrong. It’s also not the asker’s use.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet — You're right, the "Just as" is followed several miles (and commas) down the road by "so it is". Does the T in Toefl stand for "torture" (or just "tortuous")?

Comment: @David I wouldn’t call it an _elegant_ sentence, but it doesn’t seem particularly tortuous to me – no more so than most academic writing, at any rate. I probably wouldn’t have thought twice about it if I’d just read it in a normal text.

Answer (score 1):

I am distilling down the verbiage in each example, and actually rephrasing things a bit in the second in order to get it to express its essential meaning in a shorter fashion.

**1. It.**

> Just as designs on *Greek* pots seem decorative, so **it** <sup>(designs seeming decorative)</sup> is with *Chinese* pots.

**2. Their / was**.

> Although **designs on Greek pots** may seem decorative <sup>(without meaning)</sup> today, **their** <sup>(the designs on Greek pots)</sup> meaning **was** clear <sup>(when the pots were created).</sup>

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly that you don’t think the original sentence as quoted is completely comprehensible? Or are you referring only to it not being possible to make your distilled version completely comprehensible without some adjustments? Because the original sentence is perfectly comprehensible and not at all awkward to me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, the original sentence itself is unclear. One of many issues is *they were carefully and precisely worked out **so that** at the time time*. That doesn't make any sense. What role does *so that* play in the clause set off by commas? It *would* make sense if a comma came after it. Similarly, the comma after *was clear* appears to be a comma splice. It might not be, if everything earlier is parenthetical; however, there are three commas before that phrase. This is mostly to do with punctuation—but I can't determine what the grammar is supposed to be because of that.

Comment: I don’t see anything unclear about it… here’s a rephrasing of my understanding: “Chinese and Greek pots have this in common: to us in the present their painted designs may seem to be purely decorative, but they were in fact carefully and precisely made in such a way that, to the Greeks/Chinese of the time, their meaning was clear”. The only ambiguity to me is whether _their meaning_ refers to the meaning of the designs or of the pots, and that’s a minute difference.

Comment: Oh, I think I see the source of your confusion now: the comma after _at the time_ is just there to separate that (adverbial) from the following clause; the sort-of-parenthetical clause is “whereas… was clear”. Setting off _at the time_ with a comma on both sides (“so that, at the time, their meaning…”) would have been clearer, I agree.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, I can likely rephrase (or at least re-punctuate) the sentence so it makes sense. If I strike out those things between what *could* be parenthetical comma pairs, things are left in a strange state. Similarly, those things *in* what I might think of as parenthetical text are odd too. At the very least, I think one of the commas needs to be removed—or another one inserted.

Comment: I don't have any problem at all with the original version - I would have put a comma before *so that* but I think that is just personal preference. I would call the *it* a dummy it - for me it is the *so* that refers back to what has already been said, not the *it*.

Comment: I can't see any reason for the single comma. It's not needed and all it does is to interrupt the flow of the sentence. If the preposing of the adjunct is reversed a comma would clearly not be required: "so that their meaning was clear at the time".

Comment: OP wasn't asking about the commas though. Everyone seems to agree that if you are going to have one comma it would be better to have two - there is disagreement about whether a single comma is acceptable, but that doesn't seem to relate to the original question. I think this *it* is the same one you find in *it is the case that* i.e. a dummy subject.

Comment: @minty I have removed all references to the grammar in my answer. I still firmly believe that it's an issue, but it doesn't have any direct bearing on the question—and it seems to have generated a large number of comments as a side issue . . .

Answer (score 1):

The subject of *was* is *meaning*.

*It* refers to the entire language before *so*, as @BillJ says in his comment.

As you can tell from comments, the punctuation is poor.  It would have been better as two sentences. The writer is trying to say that what’s true of Greek pots is also true of Chinese pots.